# Lossless ffmpeg recordings with low resource usage

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, synchronization, recording

I'm trying to record lossless videos with `ffmpeg` of

- My screen
- My computer audio
- My microphone audio

using this script:

```
MIC="alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset-00.mono-fallback"
MONITOR="alsa_output.usb-Logitech_Logitech_USB_Headset-00.analog-stereo.monitor"

AUDIO0=$(pactl list short | grep "$MIC" | grep -Po "[0-9]+" | head -1)
AUDIO1=$(pactl list short | grep "$MONITOR" | grep -Po "[0-9]+" | head -1)

ffmpeg \
-video_size 1920x1080 \
-framerate 60 \
-f x11grab -i :0.0 \
-f pulse -i $AUDIO0 \
-f pulse -i $AUDIO1 \
-map 0 -map 1 -map 2 \
-c:a copy \
-c:v libx264rgb \
-crf 0 \
-preset ultrafast \
video.mkv
```

On my slow computer it only records at about 7 FPS. Is there a way to record at a higher FPS while keeping it lossless and the file size fairly small?

The 3 tracks also appear to be about a second out of sync with each other, with the screen first, the mic second, and the sound output third. I think it's because it recognizes them in that order when the recording is started. I can manually resync them, but it would be easier to fix the problem.

Comment: I'd recommend an external HDMI recorder.  They're easier to use and more reliable than screen capture.  Otherwise, aside from getting a faster computer, you could try reducing frame rate, lowering resolution, switching codecs.

Comment: I'm getting a faster computer soon, so I'll probably just wait until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no faster presets for x264 than `ultrafast`, so you could:

- Reduce framerate from 60 to cinematic 24 or even 15 since we are talking about screen casting
- Use a different video codec
- Use hardware video encoding acceleration if your GPU supports it
- Add `-thread_queue_size 1024` as encoding options.
- Some people say the output rate matters to have everything in sync, so try adding `-r 60`.

I see no other options. Your computer is really slow by today's standards.

Comment: Adding `-r 60` doesn't put it in sync. I'm getting a new computer soon so hopefully it'll run faster.